# Directly convert a single XML file to DOCX

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml, docx

I tried to convert a single XML file into a DOCX file, and I did it by transforming my XML into an XHTML by using XSLT, then open the XHTML on MS Word and save it as DOCX.

But my task is to convert any XML Structure (DITA, TEI, DocBook, etc.) to DOCX **directly**... are there any other way to do it?

I just can't find any sources for this. It's always DOCX to XML and not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use XSLT to transform from any of those XML formats to [OOXML](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/OpenXML%20White%20Paper.pdf).  XSLT is ideal for XML to XML transformations.

That said, each of the input XML formats you mention are fairly complex, and OOXML is immensely complex.  Also, DOCX is actually an assembly of many components, including a `document.xml` file in OOXML, packaged via [Open Packaging Conventions](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/tc45-2006-335.pdf).

To get started, I recommend that you target creation of a simple document that you first make manually in MS Word.  Rename the file from a `.docx` extension to a `.zip` extension, and unzip the components and recover the `word/document.xml` file.  Make a simple XSLT program to output the OOXML literally as it appears in the original `word/document.xml` file.  Then, slowly add in some customizations.  When you are finished, reinsert the generated `word/document.xml` file into the unzipped assembly, rezip, renaming the extension to `.docx` and you'll have directly converted XML to DOCX as requested.

For further details, see [Using XSLT and Open XML to Create a Word 2007 Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx).